# Extjs grid performance in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-11, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I am using Extjs 4.1.0 and, It's taking more time to show data of the grid panel in the IE - 11 browser, and based on the UI responsiveness tools of IE, Noticed that It's taking time in calculating layout, and Style. If we have large number of data, It shows grid and its data after 10 to 20 secs. It's taking more time in rendering.

Is there any way to overcome this problem ?

Comment: *FYI* the ExtJS-4.1.0 release date was [march 2012](https://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-rc-2-released/), Internet Explorer 11 was released in [October 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) - a whole year and a half later... You really need to keep your version of the framework up-to-date if you want to support newer browsers. I'd suggest trying to replicate your issue in ExtJS-4.2.4 which actually supports IE11, before asking us to speculate wildly.

Comment: @Emissary You are right ! Thank you

Comment: I am figuring out what are the problems and missing in Ext-4.1.0 for IE-11 as it becomes slow.